# Design of a Self Reversing Screw

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design

I am currently designing a winch for a submersible vehicle and need to implement a self reversing screw shaft in it for ensuring proper spooling of the tether cable. It's also known as diamond screw shaft.

Is there any mechanical design handbook or guidelines from where i can get the design details for design of such a screw shaft ?

To know what is a self reversing screw, please refer to this [link](http://www.abssac.co.uk/p/Self+reversing+screws/8/#.VotuS_n5i01).

Comment: My guess is that the basic stress/strength requirements are the same as for other lead screws, such as at http://www.engineersedge.com/fastener_thread_menu.shtml .

Comment: Hi Anupam Chandra, welcome to Engineering SE. This question as currently written appears to be off-topic; for details, please read [The Engineering.SE position on recommendation/finding stuff questions](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/368). If you have particular specs in mind, or an intractable problem to solve, please [edit] your question to clarify exactly what it is you need to know. A full treatment of the solution should be possible within the confines of one answer, without relying on external links or resources.